# No Data is Getting Sent to Django Rest Framework API

Tags: django, api, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am trying to send the Post objects to my API for posts where followers of a user each have a Source_id and `Source_id=Post.sourceID`. Basically, I am trying to return all the Post objects for the followers of a user in order to then render a feed. But, I am running into a problem because my API is not returning any data, even though I made sure the data is in the database.

In my views.py, this is what I am doing:

```
class FeedAPI(ObjectMultipleModelAPIView):

    #lookup_url_kwarg = 'id'
    def get_querylist(self, *args, **kwargs):
        id = self.kwargs['id']
        if id != None:
            profile = Profile.objects.filter(id=id)
            if len(profile) > 0:
                data = ProfileSerializer(profile[0]).data
                return Response(data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

        querylist = [
            {'queryset': Profile.objects.all(), 'serializer_class': ProfileSerializer},
            {'queryset': Post.objects.all(), 'serializer_class': PostSerializer},
            {'queryset': Source.objects.all(), 'serializer_class': SourceSerializer},
        ]
        props = Source.objects.filter(profile_id=id)
        followers = [f.pk for f in Profile.objects.filter(followers__in=props)]
        return followers
        feedPosts= []
        postID = Post.objects.filter()
        i=0
        length = len(followers)
        #while i < length:
            #feedPosts = list(Post.objects.filter(Source_id=Post.sourceID))
            #return feedPosts(i)
             #i+=1
        for x in followers:
            feedPosts = Post.objects.filter(Source_id=followers)
            return feedPosts(x)
        return Response(feedPosts,  status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

The url is

```
    path('feed/<int:id>', views.FeedAPI.as_view()),
```

**models**

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = AutoOneToOneField(User, default=True,  on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    sourceID = models.ForeignKey('Source', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='+', blank=True, null=True)
    followers = models.ManyToManyField( 'Source', related_name='+', default='', blank=True, null=True)
    following = models.ManyToManyField('Source', related_name='+', default='', blank=True, null=True)
```

**post**

```
class Post(models.Model):
    sourceID = models.ForeignKey('Source', blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='+', null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(
        "Post Picture", upload_to='post_pics', blank=True, null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

**Source**

```
class Source(models.Model):
    profile = models.ForeignKey('Profile', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, related_name='+')
    project= models.ForeignKey('Project', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, related_name='+')
    team = models.ForeignKey('Team', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, related_name='+')
    department = models.ForeignKey('Department', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True, related_name='+')

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)
```

**Source Serializer**

```
class SourceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    model = Source
    fields = ('id', 'profile', 'project', 'team', 'department')
```

The API does not return any data, but it should be returning data. I am very confused as to why when I return feedPosts, it doesn't achieve what I described above.